# How to delete all orphan records in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables MySQL (MyIsam):

`user (id), message (id, userId, ...), archivedMessage (id, userId, ...)`

How can I delete all the users having no message AND no archivedMessage?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `not exists`:

```
delete from user
where not exists (select * from message m where m.userid = user.id)
      and not exists (select * from archivedMessage am where am.userid = user.id)
```

Comment: Are there pros/cons against the `LEFT join... IS NULL` method?

Comment: @Toto: Functionally they're the same, but there might be performance differences