# MYSQL join query advice (removing orphaned rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables as follows..

```
campaigns(campaignID, title)
campaignMailList(campaignID, Sent)
```

(The 2 tables are bigger.. but for this purpose I only need these columns)

I want to do generate a query that will DELETE all rows in campaignMailList where it cannot find a join in the campaigns table on the campaignID.

Can anyone suggest how I do this?

Comment: You are searching to delete orphaned records , there are lots of duplicates out there e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445966/elegant-way-to-remove-orphan-rows , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804846/how-to-delete-all-orphan-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating word by word your own question into SQL:

```
delete from campaingMailList where
campaingId not in (select campaingid from campaigns)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `NOT IN` clause.
Like

```
DELETE FROM `campaignMailList` as cml
WHERE cml.campaignid NOT IN ( SELECT campaignID FROM campaigns )
```

Not sure if it is the fatest way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
DELETE cml FROM campaignMailList cml
  LEFT JOIN campaigns c
    ON c.campaignID = cml.campaignID
WHERE c.campaignID IS NULL
```